# Media in closed thermofluid loops

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I have been having a bit of difficulty balancing pressures in closed thermofluid loops for a project on a solar thermal plant, so I decided to make a simple system to iron out some bugs. Below is a simple loop between two storage tanks which works correctly using the water media from the MSL:

```
model TankTestfluid

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(
    p_a_start=system.p_ambient,
    length=20,
    height_ab=-20,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    diameter=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=-90,
        origin={50,10})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(
    p_a_start=system.p_ambient,
    length=20,
    height_ab=20,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    diameter=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=90,
        origin={-50,10})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.ControlledPump pump(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    p_a_nominal=system.p_ambient,
    m_flow_nominal=100,
    p_b_nominal=200000) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=90,
        origin={-50,-42})));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,60},{-60,80}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank1(
    height=10,
    crossArea=3,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=2,
    portsData={Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05),
        Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05)},
    level_start=7,
    use_portsData=false,
    use_HeatTransfer=false,
    T_start=363.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-12,-82},{28,-42}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank2(
    height=10,
    crossArea=3,
    nPorts=2,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    portsData={Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05),
        Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05)},
    level_start=3,
    use_portsData=false,
    use_HeatTransfer=false,
    T_start=353.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,30},{20,70}})));
//    replaceable package Medium = SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_base
//      constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium annotation (
//        __Dymola_choicesAllMatching=true);
   replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater
     constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium annotation (
       __Dymola_choicesAllMatching=true);
equation 
  connect(pump.port_b, pipe1.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-50,-32},{-50,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, tank2.ports[1]) annotation (Line(points={{-50,20},{-28,20},
          {-28,30},{-4,30}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(tank2.ports[2], pipe.port_a) annotation (Line(points={{4,30},{26,30},{
          26,20},{50,20}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, tank1.ports[1]) annotation (Line(points={{50,0},{32,0},{32,
          -82},{4,-82}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(tank1.ports[2], pump.port_a) annotation (Line(points={{12,-82},{-22,-82},
          {-22,-52},{-50,-52}}, color={0,127,255}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.2"), SolarTherm(version="0.2")));
end TankTestfluid;
```

Now, when I try to use this exact same model with a molten salt medium, I get an error. The molten salt medium I am using can be found at (in the Alberto branch):

https://github.com/SolarTherm/SolarTherm.git

The only difference (apart from the medium) I make is the starting temperatures (so the salt is still liquid):

```
model MoltenSaltTest

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(
    p_a_start=system.p_ambient,
    length=20,
    height_ab=-20,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    diameter=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=-90,
        origin={50,10})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(
    p_a_start=system.p_ambient,
    length=20,
    height_ab=20,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    diameter=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=90,
        origin={-50,10})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.ControlledPump pump(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    p_a_nominal=system.p_ambient,
    T_start=673.15,
    p_b_nominal=200000,
    m_flow_nominal=10)  annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=90,
        origin={-50,-42})));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,60},{-60,80}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank1(
    height=10,
    crossArea=3,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=2,
    portsData={Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05),
        Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05)},
    level_start=7,
    use_portsData=false,
    use_HeatTransfer=false,
    T_start=673.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-12,-82},{28,-42}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank2(
    height=10,
    crossArea=3,
    nPorts=2,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    portsData={Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05),
        Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.05)},
    level_start=3,
    use_portsData=false,
    use_HeatTransfer=false,
    T_start=573.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,30},{20,70}})));
   replaceable package Medium = SolarTherm.Media.MoltenSalt.MoltenSalt_base
     constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium annotation (
       __Dymola_choicesAllMatching=true);
   // replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater
   //   constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium annotation (
   //     __Dymola_choicesAllMatching=true);
equation 
  connect(pump.port_b, pipe1.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-50,-32},{-50,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, tank2.ports[1]) annotation (Line(points={{-50,20},{-28,20},
          {-28,30},{-4,30}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(tank2.ports[2], pipe.port_a) annotation (Line(points={{4,30},{26,30},{
          26,20},{50,20}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, tank1.ports[1]) annotation (Line(points={{50,0},{32,0},{32,
          -82},{4,-82}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(tank1.ports[2], pump.port_a) annotation (Line(points={{12,-82},{-22,-82},
          {-22,-52},{-50,-52}}, color={0,127,255}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.2"), SolarTherm(version="0.2")));
end MoltenSaltTest;
```

Now, no matter what pump mass flow rate I use, I can never fill up the 'top' tank, and in fact the top tank drains faster the greater I set the mass flow rate.

What may be the source of the error here?